# WS-FED authentication (ADFS) and ASP.NET Identity UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, adfs, ws-federation

I apologize if I use some wrong or ambiguous terms. **Please** correct me if I do.

I have a fairly new ASP.NET 4.6 MVC 5 app that uses **Claims** authentication via **WsFederation** and **Microsoft ADFS** server. That means that I **do not** expose a **LogIn** action controller nor do I manage users and passwords in my webapp. When the user navigates to my site, if they are not authenticated they are redirected to the ADFS server where they log in and then are redirected back.

I have a need to store some of the submitted claims for offline usage -- their display name and email address. My thought was to utilize the ASP.NET Identity package that creates that collection os `AspNet*` tables. It was my understanding that it is designed to support both local users (with passwords) and **external** users (with passwords managed externally) from providers like Facebook, Google, Github, etc. Am I correct that ADFS falls under that category?

And after a successful authentication redirects back to my site, where exactly do I put the logic that checks if the user has entry in the `AspNet*` tables? The configuration and wiring up of the cookie authentication and WsFederation currently happens in the `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` method. I think I am supposed to use classes that inherit from `IdentityUser` and `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and then call methods on `UserManager` or `UserStore`.

I have spent hours searching for examples of how to associate the external logins with the application "profile" tables to no avail. It is **very** possible that I have just been using the wrong terms. Every example I have found so far deals with either emulating or modifying the default VS template that comes with Login and Register action methods or just hooking up FB and Google. Nothing that deals with ADFS **and/or** tying into the profile tables from external sources.

Any code examples or at the very least links to articles/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar question for my case here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501580/sso-with-ad-fs-and-owin-how-to-create-an-account-and-handle-permissions . Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ADFS is an external provider but be aware that it uses WS-Fed whereas the social logins are all OAuth.

Have a look at [Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on).

You'll see it has a linking mechanism.

Also [OWIN : ASP.NET MVC application with multiple authentication options](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/01/owin-adpnet-mvc-application-with.html) which has an example of adding ADFS.

Comment: Thank you for the links but I am not sure how much they are helping. I created a new project using the default MVC Individual User Accounts template and added WS-Federation afterwards. On the Login page I get the option to use "another service" and when clicked it redirects me to ADFS server. I enter credentials and get sent back to project site. All good...kind of had this working already. The problem is that, by default, everything is set to AllowAnonymous. Once I add Authorize attribute I start getting redirect loops and cannot seem to resolve.

Comment: Hi @Jason I know it’s been a few years now. I encountered the same issue recently, did you manage to fix this issue? If yes could you share some details? Thanks