# SSO with AD FS and OWIN how to create an account and handle permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs, ws-federation

I configure a Web App that use AD FS, for this I use OWIN.

For the login, all is ok. If i'm an user of a domain and go to the website, he is automatically connected.

But what I want to have is to handle users and roles by myself after login.

So I want to check that an user exists in my database with this AD account (this process will be make before the login in another application)

I want to use Identity from Microsoft to handle claims (roles and permissions). But I don't understand how to put my code to handle the successfull connection from AD FS (with Ws-Federation) and add verification and fill in the right roles.

My code in ConfigureAuth:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
    private NLogLoggingService _loggingService;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        _loggingService = new NLogLoggingService("Startup");
        _loggingService.Debug("ConfigureAuth");

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,

                //CallbackPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/Account/TestCallback"),

                // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationmode(v=vs.113).aspx
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,

                //Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                //{

                //}
            });

    }
```

In Web.config, realm is the link to my Web App (https://ssoadfs.test) and adfsMetadata is the link to metadata.xml from AD FS.

What is the way to go to set my role and login logic after AD FS connection ?

Schema that what I was thinking:

[image]

EDIT:
After some tries, I cannot handle any success callback. I don't want to have to handle roles in HomeController ...

My last Auth config:

```
            _loggingService = new NLogLoggingService("Startup");
        _loggingService.Debug("ConfigureAuth");

        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationUser.ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
                {
                    _loggingService.Debug("OnResponseSignIn");
                    ctx.Identity = TransformClaims(ctx, app);
                },
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
                Caption = "Active Directory",

                CallbackPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/Account/TestCallback"),

                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        new NLogLoggingService("Startup").Debug("SecurityTokenValidated");

                        var incomingClaimsFromAdfs = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.ToList();
                        var incomingClaimsHasNameIdentifier =
                            incomingClaimsFromAdfs.Any(
                                c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

                        _loggingService.Debug("SecurityTokenValidated - incomingClaimsHasNameIdentifier: " +
                                              incomingClaimsHasNameIdentifier);
                        if (!incomingClaimsHasNameIdentifier)
                        {
                            var emailClaim =
                                incomingClaimsFromAdfs.First(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name);
                            _loggingService.Debug(emailClaim.Value);
                        }

                        //if (!incomingClaimsHasNameIdentifier)
                        //{
                        //    var emailClaim = incomingClaimsFromAdfs.First(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name);
                        //    incomingClaimsFromAdfs.Add();

                        //    IUser user = await this.UserStore.FindByNameOrEmailAsync(userNameOrEmailAddress);
                        //    if ((Entity<long>)user == (Entity<long>)null)
                        //        LoginResult = new ApplicationUserManager.LoginResult(LoginResultType.InvalidUserNameOrEmailAddress, default(IUser));
                        //    //else if (!loggedInFromExternalSource && new PasswordHasher().VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, plainPassword) != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                        //    //    LoginResult = new UserManager<TTenant, TRole, TUser>.LoginResult(LoginResultType.InvalidPassword, user);
                        //    else
                        //        LoginResult = await this.CreateLoginResultAsync(user, tenant);
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    throw new ApplicationException("Get ADFS to provide the NameIdentifier claim!");
                        //}

                        //var normalizedClaims = incomingClaimsFromAdfs.Distinct(new ClaimComparer());
                        //var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(normalizedClaims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                        //n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

In this code, I tried CallbackPath (nothing appeared in my log), WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated (nothing appeared in my log), CookieAuthenticationProvider.OnResponseSignIn (same nothing happened)

In HomeController i'm able to have Identity.Name:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            new NLogLoggingService("Home").Debug("User is authenticated");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Did I miss something to get Notifications working or Provider in CookieAuthenticationOptions ???

Comment: Using AD and Identity is not and out of the box option. You're stuck creating that functionality. You will need 2 UserManager instances configured distinctly...

Comment: Can you delevop the "2 UserManager instances" ? For now, I think to create a Wep API that works with AD WS-Federation (still todo) and then call anoher method with the cookie to check if user exists in Database as User.

Comment: @user18620 Hello, not really a solution ... but I check this in AccountController.AuthenticationCallbackAD() by setting the default route in App_Start/RouteConfig. Inside this method I create the user or check if he is validated using ASP.NET Identity UserManager. And add custom claims.

Comment: Did you find a final solution to this problem?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón No, I keep it working in HomeController for now, not a beautiful implementation but I didn't have the time to make some search for a better solution

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ASP.NET Identity 2.0` or later version, you can use an approach similar to it shown below. Please note that this approach assign `GroupRoles` to the user instead of assigning each of roles one by one. You can change necessary parts according to your needs.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    ApplicationGroupManager groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

        //Assign Roles to the current User
        ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);

        //If the user is registered in the system (ASP.NET Identity) add record to AspNetUsers table 
        if (user != null)
        {
            //Returns Group Id and Role Id by using User Id parameter
            var userGroupRoles = groupManager.GetUserGroupRoles("bfd9730e-2093-4fa0-89a2-226e301d831b"); 
            foreach (var role in userGroupRoles)
            {
                string roleName = RoleManager.FindById(role.ApplicationRoleId).Name;
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //crate new user
            //first retrieve user info from LDAP:
            // Create an array of properties that we would like and add them to the search object  
            string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "samaccountname", "givenname", "sn", "mail", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "title" };
            var userInfo = CreateDirectoryEntry(model.UserName, requiredProperties);

            var newUser = new ApplicationUser();
            newUser.UserName = userInfo.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();
            newUser.Name = userInfo.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenname"].Value.ToString();
            newUser.Surname = userInfo.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
            newUser.Email = userInfo.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
            newUser.EmailConfirmed = true;
            newUser.PasswordHash = null;

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //If the user is created ...
            }

            //Assign user group (and roles)
            var defaultGroup = "751b30d7-80be-4b3e-bfdb-3ff8c13be05e";
            groupManager.SetUserGroups(newUser.Id, new string[] { defaultGroup });
        }
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Issue");
    }

    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Wrong username or password!");
    return this.View(model);
}


static SearchResult CreateDirectoryEntry(string sAMAccountName, string[] requiredProperties)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;

    try
    {
        ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=******, DC=******, DC=******", "acb@xyz.com", "YourPassword");
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
        search.Filter = String.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", sAMAccountName);

        foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);

        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        //SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = search.FindAll(); //You can also retrieve all information

        if (result != null)
        {                
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return null;
            //Console.WriteLine("User not found!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hello Murat, thanks to trying to help me. But my problem is more that I can't handle a callback in the right way of OWIN. I will never pass in a Login page as it is an application SSO (so the user is authenticated by Owin before to get in my Application). For now, I add logic in HomeController to check if the user is authenticated then add user in UserManager ... :(

Comment: You are welcome Jerome. I could not understand why your used HomeController instead of AccountController? On the other hand, if you have enough time and not used ASP.NET Identity 2.0 or later, you might have a look at the articles like [ASP.NET MVC and Identity 2.0: Understanding the Basics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics). Good luck :)

Comment: I use AspNet.Identity.Core, .EntityFramework, .Owin. But I would like to use AD FS and Owin, to simplify configuration (only needed the metadata.xml from AD). I use a code similar to your with UserManager from Identity and it's not a choice to add this logic in HomeController. I could put it In AccountController with defining the default Route. But I'm sure that Owin can help me to handle that in Startup Auth Config